# Swagger 2.0 support in Grails 3+ (3.0.11) not working

Tags: spring, grails, swagger

I am running Grails 3.0.11 and want to create Swagger-documentation for my REST endpoints. I added the [SwaggyDoc](https://github.com/rahulsom/swaggydoc)-[plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/swaggydoc) to the dependencies in my build.gradle script by adding:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc:0.26.0".
```

In IntelliJ I see the Swaggydoc-dependency added to my list of libraries.

After starting my Grails-application via the grails run-app command and opening my application by entering http://localhost:8080/api/ I get an 404 error telling the page does not exist.

Do I need to configure something more or to run something special to generate documentation? I already tried to open a ticket in the Git-project and contacting the author with no succes.

**Update1**: there seems to be a Grails 3-plugin (found at Versioneye?) which I added:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc-grails3:0.26.0"
```

It does work half, by default some sort of Pet-demo is visible and it is failing on constraints in a domain and enums. Doesn't seem to work very well actually.

**Update2**: As pointed out by Dilip Krishnan I tried to use SpringFox, first I added the dependencies to my Gradle build file:

```
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.3.1")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.3.1")
```

Then I added a new class called *ApiDocumentationConfiguration* with the following code:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableSwagger2
 public class ApiDocumentationConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public Docket documentation() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
 }

 @Bean
 public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
 }

 private ApiInfo metadata() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
           .title("My awesome API")
            .description("Some description")
            .version("1.0")
            .contact("my-email@domain.org")
            .build();
 }
}
```

My Grails resources file contains the following code:

```
beans = {
    apiDocumentationConfiguration(ApiDocumentationConfiguration)
}
```

Last step was starting the application and trying to load the end point which shows the Swagger front end:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

It behind the scenes tries to load an other end point (containing the JSON I guess?) which loads

```
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs
```

This does show JSON data and I get end points for things like a basic error controller, health mvc, metrics mvc et cetera. But not my own annotated user controller which is annotated like follows:

```
@Api(value = "users", description = "Endpoint for user management")
class UserController { 

    // GET all users
    @ApiOperation(value = "doStuff", nickname = "doStuff", response = User.class)
    def index() {
        respond User.list()
    }
}
```

Seems I am almost there, but still missing something, is my annotation wrong or doesn't it scan my controllers?

**Update3**: in contact with one of the authors of SpringFox (Dilip Krishnan) to add support for Grails 3+ to SpringFox, see [ticket](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1169). The reason it doesn't currently work is because SpringFox looks at MVC annotation, an adapter needs to be written to retrieve the endpoints from the controllers in Grails.

Comment: Did you try custom mapping described here: http://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/guide/customization.html ?

Comment: @majkelo I added the line  `/myapi" (controller: "api")` to the `UrlMappings`-class and still it gives an "error 404 (_page not found_)", "path _/myapi_" - it feels like as if the controller isn't generated/running on startup?

Comment: Since grails 3.x is built on spring 4.x you could try using [springfox](http://springfox.io)

Comment: @DilipKrishnan thanks, I didn't know that and tried it, but I updated my original question with some additional information, I can't get it working correctly yet, what am I missing?

Comment: @Tjeerd one thing to try is to use version `2.3.1` rather than `2.1.1`

Comment: @DilipKrishnan I replaced it with the newer version and the NPE is gone now. Actually JSON data is returned correctly, but now my own controller(s) are not picked up?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't really tried using springfox with a grails app nor am I very familiar with grails. I suggested it cos it's based on spring and I know groovy based spring mvc apps is supported. Let me try and put together a sample so see what the gaps might be or better still see if I can solve ur problem.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan I created an example Grails 3 'Hello World' project which can be found at https://github.com/tjeerdnet/grails3springfox, could you look into that?

Comment: I did a little digging and it looks like with a little bit of effort we could get it working. Springfox relies on request mappings which is a spring mvc construct. What needs to happen is to write an adapter that will take a groovyApplication and *infer* the request mappings.

Comment: Just a quick update. In the process of releasing [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration) Would love to get feedback on it.

Answer (score 10):

I have successfully used swaggydocs in both 2.4.x projects and 3.1.4. 
In order to make it work in 3.x (tested on 3.1.4) you have to add

```
    compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc-grails3:0.26.0"
```

to gradle dependencies section. That makes swaggy available in your project.

Then add annotations to your controllers

```
@Api("test methods")
class TestController {
@ApiOperation(value = "some method description")
@ApiResponses([
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Bad method. Only POST is allowed"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid request json")
])
def testGetMethod() {
    render([status: "OK"] as JSON)
}
```

Then mark your methods allowedMethods as follows

```
class TestController {
static allowedMethods = [testGetMethod: "GET", testPostMethod: "POST"]
```

NOTE this is really important - otherwise swaggy will mark every your method as GET. Swaggy doesn't respect neither httpMethod in ApiOperation annotation nor http method in url mappings.

Finally add your controller to urlmappings as swaggy checks url mappings to look for URLS. Note camelCase!

```
//NOTE small camelCase
//swaggy won't see urls correctly if you start controller name with capital letter
"/api/test/"(controller: "test", action: "testGetMethod")
"/api/test/"(controller: "test", action: "testPostMethod")
```

You can also add some api info in application.yml

```
swaggydoc:
    contact: rafal@pydyniak.pl
    description: sample swaggy app
```

You can find sample app (with dummy methods but point was to make swaggy work) at my github https://github.com/RafalPydyniak/Swaggy-example.
Also there are some more docs on how to use this api on http://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/. I just wanted to show you how to install it (as it's quite tricky to make everything work)

Hope it helps!

Comment: do you have an example of your implementation for the 2.4.x app?

Comment: @JJHolloway do you still need it? I don't have such example but I guess I could make one for you if you are still in need :)

Comment: all working now thanks.  The swaggerDoc API controller was being blocked by a security plugin.  Once I 'moved it' to allowed it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

I followed the same 2 steps:
1) add swagger2 dependencies
2) provide configuation
The problem is that sprinfox does not scan grails url mappings (see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1169#issuecomment-252259284)
To fix that I added standard spring annotations:

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping(value="/path")
```

on the controller and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resource")
```

on the method. After that sprinfox started to pick up my documentation.

Comment: Also to make swagger-ui to work I had to add
`    resources:
        pattern: '/**'
`
under `grails` in application.yml

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. There is now first class support for it in [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration).