# Basic Authorization for SwaggerUI generated RESTful services in Groovy/Grails

Tags: database, grails, groovy, swagger

Sorry for my naive question.
I want to test basic authorization in my swaggerUI generated REST endpoints documentation.

I have generated some api-docs with SwaggerUI plugin containing many endpoints.

An example can be found here:

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/mghaffar/TestAPI/1.0.0#/

Here, a basic Authorization has been applied. I want to use this basic scheme and allow users to access these endpoint depending on their access permissions. For example: there are three users, one can have access to all three endpoints, others have access to only one or two endpoints.

Now, how do I implement this in my grails/groovy project.

Comment: I put together a simple Grails 3 app to test spring security rest a while back here, https://github.com/leadtrip/carhub, I used the grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap in application.groovy to restrict access to endpoints, not to the granular level you want but this is possible, just look at the docs, https://github.com/leadtrip/carhub/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.groovy

Comment: Could you please explain me what is going on here. I can open the endpoints without any security. and when I call [/localhost:9090/grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController](/grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController), I simply get page not found error.

Comment: Remember this is all REST based, you login using this method too, not via a browser, in the description I mention a postman file included in the project, import this into postman then perform the various actions including logging in to allow access to v3

Comment: I think, I need to spend some time on postman to learn on how to use it. Anyway, why your swagger documentation looks different as mine?

Comment: Different versions I guess, my project uses a grails plugin & generates the docs from the API & my annotations, it seems to be unmaintained now however, https://github.com/rahulsom/swaggydoc, I remember using the answer here to get it working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164199/swagger-2-0-support-in-grails-3-3-0-11-not-working